# Can't initialize KendoDropdownList inside a KendoGrid Toolbar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm trying to add a toolbar on a Kendo UI grid, but it seems that the grid cannot render the content of @Html.Partial("FiltriTemporali") as dropdownlists.

this is the view in which i have the Grid

```
    @Html.Partial("FiltriTemporali")
    <div id="grid">
    </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid(
        {
            sortable: true,
            dataSource: {
                data:mergedData,
                pageSize: 50,
                group: {
                    field: "GruppoStatistica",
                    aggregates: [],
                }
            },
            scrollable: { 
                virtual: true
            },
            pageable: true,
            resizable: false,
            selectable: true,
            columnMenu: true,
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#toolbar-template").html()),
            navigatable: true,
            groupable: true,
            columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                name: "id",
                hidden: true
            }, {
                field: "GruppoStatistica",
                name: "Gruppo Statistica",
                hidden: true,
                groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #"
            }, {
                field: "CodiceStatistica",
                name: "Codice Statistica"
            }, {
                field: "TitoloStatistica",
                name: "Titolo Statistica"
            }, {
                field: "Descrizione",
                name: "Descrizione"
            }, {
                width: 80,
                template:
                    '# if (data.QueryOverride !== "") { #' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-user-edit personalizzato">' +
                        '<span style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size:13px;">@L("Personalizzato")</span>' +
                        '</i>' +
                    '# } #'
            }, {
                width: 120,
                template:
                    '# if (data.StatisticaTypeId == 0) { #' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-calendar personalizzato">' +
                        '<span id="rangeMonth-#= data.Id #" style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size:13px;"></span>' +
                        '</i>' +
                    '# } else if (data.StatisticaTypeId == 1) { #' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-calendar personalizzato">' +
                        '<span id="singleMonth-#= data.Id #" style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size:13px;"></span>' +
                        '</i>' +
                    '# } else { #' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-calendar personalizzato">' +
                        '<span id="annuale-#= data.Id #" style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size:13px;"></span>' +
                        '</i>' +
                    '# } #' +
                    '<i class="fas fa-lock personalizzato">'+
                        '<span style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size:13px;">@L("Ereditato")</span>'+
                    '</i>'
            }, {
                width: 120,
                template:
                    '# if (data.NomeReport === "") { #' +
                        '<a type="button" onclick="exportElement(#= data.Id #)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm delete" title="@G("Export")"><i class="fas fa-file-excel-o"></i></a>' +
                    '# } else { #' +
                        '<a type="button" onclick="printElement(#= data.Id #)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm delete" title="@G("Print")"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a>' +
                    '# } #' +
                    '# if (document.getElementById("generateXml").value === 1) { #' +
                        '<a type="button" onclick="exportXML(#= data.Id #)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm delete" title="@G("ExportXml")" style="height: 24px; padding: 3px !important;"><i>XML</i></a>' +
                    '# } #'
            }, {
              field: "DataUltimaModifica",
              title: "Data Ultima Modifica",
              hidden: true,
              template: function (dataItem) {
                if (dataItem.DataUltimaModifica !== null && dataItem.DataUltimaModifica !== undefined) {
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(dataItem.DataUltimaModifica.substr(6)));
                    var formattedDate = kendo.toString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    return '<td class="v-align" style="display: none" id="tRow-' + dataItem.Id + '-date">' +
                            formattedDate +
                            '</td>';
                } else {
                  return '';
                }
              }
            }]
        });
});
```

This instead is the content of the @Html.Partial("FiltriTemporali").
The content inside it gets displayed normally as it should be, but it cannot initialize the inputs as kendoDropDownList. It seems like that JQuery can't find $("#Anno") and i don't know why.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="toolbar-template">
    <div class="generalContainer">
        <div class="timeFilterContainer">
            ANNO
            <br />
            <input id="Anno" class="filterAnno" style="color:black!important"/>
        </div>
        <div class="timeFilterContainer">
            DA
            <br />
            <input id="MeseDa" class="filterMeseDa" style="color:black!important"/>
        </div>
        <div class="timeFilterContainer">
            A
            <br />
            <input id="MeseA" class="filterMeseA" style="color:black!important"/>
        </div>
        <div class="titolo">
            <p class="displayNomeStatistica"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Anno").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Anni)),
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            change: function (e) {
                // yadda yadda
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                var dropdownlist = e.sender;
                var dataItems = dropdownlist.dataSource.data();

                for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {
                    if (dataItems[i].Selected) {
                        this.text(dataItems[i].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#MeseDa").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MesiA)),
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            change: function (e) {
                var value = this.value();
            }
        });

        $("#MeseA").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MesiA)),
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            change: function (e) {
                var value = this.value();
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                var dropdownlist = e.sender;
                var dataItems = dropdownlist.dataSource.data();

                for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {
                    if (dataItems[i].Selected) {
                        this.text(dataItems[i].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```